# jQuery get selected checkbox values in array

Tags: jquery, html

I have my markup like this. I want to get the each selected values inside an array. So that I can use them in my php ajax file.

```
<form id="assign-files">
    <table class="send-request">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="translation_document_id[]" value="4" >
                </td>
                <td>File 124</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="translation_document_id[]" value="5" >
                </td>
                <td>File New</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="translation_document_id[]" value="8" >
                </td>
                <td>New Docs</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="translation_document_id[]" value="28" >
                </td>
                <td>New Docs here</td>
            </tr>                               
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="assign btn btn-primary pull-right">Assign Files</button>
</form>
```

My jquery file is like this

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', 'button.assign', function() {
        var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name="translation_document_id[]"]:checked').length > 0;
        if( atLeastOneIsChecked == true ) {
            var ids = [];
            var Selected = $(this).parents('form').find('input[type=checkbox]');
            Selected.find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
                var obj = {};
                obj["id"]=$(this).val();
        });
        console.log(ids);
        }
        if( atLeastOneIsChecked == false ) {
            alert('select at least one checkbox');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here I don't get the values for the selected checkbox. How to get the selected values like an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your selector is not correct.
2. You are not adding object to array.

*Code*

```
var ids = [];
var form = $(this).parents('form'); 
form.find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
    var obj = {};
    obj["id"] = $(this).val();

    //Push to array
    ids.push(obj)
});
```

Alternatively, `.map()` can be used

```
var ids = $(this).parents('form').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    return {
        id: $(this).val()
    }
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/34/)**

This should work :

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.assign', function() {
    var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name="translation_document_id[]"]:checked');
    if( atLeastOneIsChecked.length ) {
        var ids = [];
        var Selected = $(this).parents('form').find('input[name="translation_document_id[]"]:checked');
        Selected.each(function(pos,element) {
            ids.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(ids);
    } else {
        alert('select at least one checkbox');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us have a look at these two lines in your code:

```
 var Selected = $(this).parents('form').find('input[type=checkbox]');
 Selected.find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
```

The code is finding checkbox checked element in selector. which do not exist. You should rather use filter instead of find here. also using `.map()` is cleaner way to get the collection of info associated with object:

```
var Selected = $(this).parents('form').find(':checkbox:checked');
var selectedids = Selected.map(function(i) {
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Comment: @NewUser: check the updated answer. needed val instead of id